# How to retrieve NavItem in liferay freemarker base theme in liferay 7?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

i had used below code but it is not working.

<#assign navItem = objectUtil("com.liferay.portal.kernel.theme.NavItem") />

it give below error.

Caused by: freemarker.core._TemplateModelException: Java constructor "com.liferay.portal.kernel.theme.NavItem.com.liferay.portal.kernel.theme.NavItem(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.Layout, Map)" takes 3 arguments, but 0 was given.__----_FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related)

I had also used below code it is also not working.
<#assign navItemClass = portal.getClass().forName("com.liferay.portal.kernel.theme.NavItem")>

Basically i want to retrieve NavItem object in theme and want to use it.

Comment: I'm wondering what you would like to do with an empty, uninitialized `NavItem` object. This is another way of asking: What's the problem that you're trying to solve with this?

Comment: Basically i wanted to retrieve parent sites pages in each child site where i want to apply theme.  This is code for the get the parent site pages.
<#assign parentNavItems = navItemClass.fromLayouts(request,parentLayouts, null)>

Comment: I am able to get it now but throug <#assign navItemClass = staticUtil["com.liferay.portal.kernel.theme.NavItem"] />  Thanks sir

Answer (score 1):

The scripting context gets a large part of its variables injected by [`TemplateContextHelper`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/template/TemplateContextHelper.java). In there you can find several relevant values for the underlying problem that you describe in the comment to your question:

- `layout` is representing the current page (layout is the technical name)
- `layouts` is a collection of all pages
- the same values can be retrieved through `themeDisplay`
- `navItems` is a collection of all navItems, but you'll have to find the one relating to the current page yourself. It might be easier to go through `layout`

Browsing through the `TemplateContextHelper` sourcecode might give you the hints you need.

Comment: Thanks for answer I am able to retrieve parent site pages in child site. some line of codes <#assign parentSiteName = "Guest"><#assign parentSiteGroup = groupService1.getGroup(theme_display.getCompanyId(),parentSiteName)><#assign parentLayouts = layoutService.getLayouts(parentSiteGroup.getGroupId(), true,0)> <#assign parentNavItems = navItemClass.fromLayouts(request,parentLayouts, null)>